# How to simplify code to check ranges in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

with columns as L, W, H, D. Each of them have range from 10 to 100, if it goes beyond this it is fail else it is pass

How can i simplify this code. I tried using if condition which failed

```
def Target(FM):

     if (df['L'] < 10 or df['L'] > 120):
        return 'L-Fail'
     else:
        return 'Pass'


     elif (df['W'] < 10 or df['W'] > 120):
        return 'W-Fail'
     else:
        return 'Pass'


     elif (df['H'] < 10 or df['H'] > 120):
        return 'H-Fail'
     else:
        return 'Pass'


     elif(df['D'] < 10 or df['D'] > 120):
        return 'D-Fail'
     else:
        return 'Pass'


     df['Remarks_Target'] = df.apply(Target, axis = 1)

      L       W       H       D     Remarks

      1       20      30      40    L-Fail
      10      40      0       50    Pass
      15      30      30      60    Pass
      60      90      80      300   D-Fail
      50      30      30      120   Pass
      10      10      120     120   Pass
      30      20      9       80    H-Fail
      14      5       85      34    W-Fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop per each column and set new values by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), last missing values for non matched data replace by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
for c in ['L','W','H','D']:
    m = df[c].between(10, 120, inclusive=True)
    df.loc[~m, 'Remarks_Target'] = f'{c}-Fail'

df['Remarks_Target'] = df['Remarks_Target'].fillna('Pass')
print (df)
    L   W    H    D Remarks Remarks_Target
0   1  20   30   40  L-Fail         L-Fail
1  10  40    0   50  H-Fail         H-Fail
2  15  30   30   60    Pass           Pass
3  60  90   80  300  D-Fail         D-Fail
4  50   0   30  120  W-Fail         W-Fail
5  10  10  120  120    Pass           Pass
```

Similar alternative:

```
df['Remarks_Target'] = 'Pass'
for c in ['L','W','H','D']:
    m = df[c].between(10, 120, inclusive=True)
    df.loc[~m, 'Remarks_Target'] = f'{c}-Fail'
```

Comment: I need to add one more condition for the above, where l,w,h,d is not equal to zero, then check the range,

Comment: @anaghas - do you think `m = df[c].between(10, 120, inclusive=True) | df[c].eq(0)` or  `m = df[c].between(10, 120, inclusive=True) & df[c].eq(0)` ?

Comment: I would need the second one, where, first i check the condition if they are not 0, then check the range, if they fall in that range then its pass else fail. So basically 0 value should not be fail condition but pass

Comment: @anaghas - if use new condition, output data are changed? If yes, what is expected output?

Comment: I will update in the question. So the expected output should be whenever there is 0 value in either column, it should be a pass case and not fail

Comment: For me working `m = df[c].between(10, 120, inclusive=True) | df[c].eq(0)` instead `m = df[c].between(10, 120, inclusive=True)`

Answer (score 1):

alternative

```
df['Remarks'] = df.astype(int).applymap(lambda x: (x < 10 or x > 120))\
                .apply(lambda x: ''.join([df2.columns[i] + '-Fail' for i in 
                range(len(x)) if x[i]]),axis=1).replace('','Pass')
```

---

```
    L   W    H    D Remarks
0   1  20   30   40  L-Fail
1  10  40    0   50  H-Fail
2  15  30   30   60    Pass
3  60  90   80  300  D-Fail
4  50   0   30  120  W-Fail
5  10  10  120  120    Pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Create boolean mask `df_m` directly on the whole `df`. Next, use `dot` and string concat and `fillna`

```
df_m = ((df < 10) | (df > 120))
df['Remarks'] = (df_m.dot(df.columns).str[0] + '-Fail').fillna('pass')

Out[293]:
    L   W    H    D Remarks
0  1   20  30   40   L-Fail
1  10  40  0    50   H-Fail
2  15  30  30   60   pass
3  60  90  80   300  D-Fail
4  50  0   30   120  W-Fail
5  10  10  120  120  pass
```